# video.js encrypt or hide video source url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-streaming, video.js

How can I hide or encrypt a [videojs](https://videojs.com/) video source URL? I want disable my video url, eg. `mysite/video.mp4`.

```
<video id="player" class="video-js" width='500' height='400'>
  <source src="http://mysite/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://mysite/video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

```js
videojs('player', {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: true,
  preload: 'auto',
  controlBar: {
    muteToggle: false
  },
});
```

Comment: You can't. For a resource to be public, its address has to be public.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any other option or suggestion ?

Comment: Not really. If you want to restrict access to the video content, add some kind of user authentication to the site

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can convert your source URL to blob by using
URL.createObjectURL(blob)